# Google Cloud External IP (Ephemeral) redirect to another IP for WordPress Admin Page

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, external-ip

Recently, i moved my WordPress website to Google Cloud. Today, Google showed a "Recommendation" to change my server for saving some monthly fee. I clicked on it and it changed my plan.

I observed that Google changed my External IP Address. When i clicked on it, it shows my website but when it try to login to my wordpress admin page. It redirected to old IP address with Page not found error and does not show my wordpress dashboard.

I observed that the External IP address is Ephemeral. What should i do to solve this issue? Please help me. I am new Google Cloud.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 2):

Your chances of getting the previous IP address back are very slim. It's possible it has already been reassigned to another customer. There are two ways you can attempt to get your old IP address back, but neither is likely to succeed:

- Allocate a few static IP addresses in the same region and hope you get your old IP back.
- Contact Google Support and hope you are lucky enough that they can help you.

To prevent your IP address from changing again, you need to convert it from ephemeral to static. Converting the IP address from ephemeral to static can be done while the VM is running and does not cause the IP address to change.

You also need to update any DNS entries pointing to the old IP address so they will instead point to the new. And if you have any configuration files with the old IP address hardcoded, you will need to update those. Since the VM sits behind a 1-1 NAT and doesn't know its own external IP address, it's not very likely that configuration files on the VM contains the external IP address. But if you cannot get things to work, it is still a thing to watch out for.

You should also keep in mind that for highest availability you should not rely solely on a single region. Two ways to achieve redundancy across regions are:

- Use HTTP(S) load balancing with backends in two or more regions. (This solution has the added benefit that you get IPv6 support)
- Deploy your site on static regional IPs in two or more regions and put all of those static IPs in your DNS records.

Comment: He apparently got a 404 page hitting that old IP address, so it's gone. Someone else has it. No getting it back.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It depends. Was that a Google branded 404 page or not? If it was a Google branded 404 page it may be produced by infrastructure which sees all traffic destined for currently unused IP addresses.

Comment: AFAIK on Google Cloud nothing answers unused IP addresses; any connection attempts to them just timeout.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not 100% certain what the behavior is. When did you last verify how it behaved? It's quite possible that it's been changed since then.

Comment: I last verified how it behaved about 15 seconds before I posted that comment.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It could be different depending on which network tier you are using. And it could take a few minutes from an IP address is released before it shows a 404. Given that the question isn't very specific about the error message I am not going to conclude that it actually was a 404. Ultimately I don't think it is all that important anyway, since even if the IP address is currently free, there isn't any guaranteed way of getting it back.